# How to rebuild the array with only values from key-value object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to rebuild the existing key/value object into another array with only values of original object.

Here is a look.

```
var car = {"key1": value1, "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"};
```

I want to change above javascript object into the following:

```
var new_car = [value1, value2, value3]
```

I need your help. Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: Is your `value1` really an object or a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and map the values with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Caveat: The order may be not guaranteed, because the properties of objects have no order.

```js
var car = {"key1": 'value1', "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"},
    new_car = Object.keys(car).map(function (k) { return car[k]; });

console.log(new_car);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply iterate it over using for :

```
var car = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"};
var new_car = [];
for ( key in car)
{
    new_car.push(car[key]);
}
```

Comment: fails as `value1` is undefined

Comment: It should work now. The value1 should be in double quote.

Comment: much faster solution than the accepted one that is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Using lodash/underscore:

```
var car = {"key1": value1, "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"};

var new_car = _.values(car);
```